# How in the model we can use localization string for the error message

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation

I use this class

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "Username is required") ]    
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Though when I try to use this code

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = Localization.UserNameRequired) ]    
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

It throws the compile error and doesn't allow me to use this localized string. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not pass the value of the resource to the `ErrorMessage` property, you should rather use the `ErrorMessageResourceName` and `ErrorMessageResourceType` properties:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameRequired", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Resources.Localization))]
public string UserName { get; set; }
```

Take a look at the [`following blog post`](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/12/11/localizing-aspnetmvc-validation.aspx) for more details about localization in ASP.NET MVC.

Comment: Thank you so much. This is the best answer on this question!

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is specify the `ErrorMessageResourceType` and `ErrorMessageResourceName`. The framework will do the rest for you. Just make sure the `UserNameRequired` resource is public.

Here is what your attribute would look like:

```
[Required(ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Localization), ErrorMessageResourceName = "UserNameRequired") ]
```

This [article](http://afana.me/post/aspnet-mvc-internationalization.aspx) has a nice write up on how the rest of your Localization resources should be defined as well. It even goes on to show how you can dynamically switch between localized versions on the fly.